# Serverless offline - Migration on local dynamoDb is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm working in a Serverless project and I'm having issues to run locally my application with dynamodb. It is not creating a data table thus not executing correctly the seed. What is wrong with my configurations?

start command: `$ sls offline start --stage dev`

error message:

```
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
Serverless: Watching for changes...
Dynamodb Local Started, Visit: http://localhost:8000/shell

  Resource Not Found Exception ---------------------------

  ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table
      at Request.extractError (/home/mauricio/dev/project/covid-favor-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
      at Request.callListeners (/home/mauricio/dev/project/covid-favor-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
      at Request.emit (/home/mauricio/dev/project/covid-favor-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
      at Request.emit (/home/mauricio/dev/project/covid-favor-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              12.13.0
     Framework Version:         1.64.0
     Plugin Version:            3.4.0
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

Serverless file:

```
org: mauriciocoder
app: covid-favor
# We are using JEST for testing: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html - npm test
service: covid-favor-app-api

# Create an optimized package for our functions
package:
  individually: true

# Create our resources with separate CloudFormation templates
resources:
  # API Gateway Handler
  - ${file(resources/api-gateway-handler.yml)}
  # DynamoDb Handler
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb-handler.yml)}

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle # Package our functions with Webpack
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin # Load .env as environment variables

custom:
  authorizer:
    dev: 
    prod: aws_iam
  dynamodb:
    stages: dev
    start:
      port: 8000 # always se port 8000, otherwise serverless-dynamodb-client will not find
      migrate: true # creates tables from serverless config
      seed: true # determines which data to onload
    seed:
      domain:
        sources:
          - table: userAccount
            sources: [./resources/migrations/v0.json]

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-east-1

  # These environment variables are made available to our functions
  # under process.env.
  environment:
    helpTableName: help
    userAccountTableName: userAccount

  # 'iamRoleStatements' defines the permission policy for the Lambda function.
  # In this case Lambda functions are granted with permissions to access DynamoDB.
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:*"

  # These are the usage plan for throttling
  usagePlan:
    throttle:
        burstLimit: 2
        rateLimit: 1

functions: ...
```

dynamodb-handler file:

```
userAccount:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  DeletionPolicy : Retain
  Properties:
    TableName: userAccount
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: userId
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: userId
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

seed file v0.json:

```
{
    "Table": {
        "TableName": "userAccount",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "userId",
                "KeyType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "LocalSecondaryIndexes": [
            {
                "IndexName": "local_index_1",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "userId",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        }
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "notes-app-api",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "A Node.js starter for the Serverless Framework with async/await and unit test support",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "serverless-bundle test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-nodejs-starter.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.622.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "serverless-bundle": "^1.2.5",
    "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "serverless-dynamodb-client": "0.0.2",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.35",
    "stripe": "^8.20.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had it working a while ago. I remember I had to do something like ```sls dynamodb start -p 8000  --migrate true```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the migration block, where you specify your migration file. put this under your `dynamodb:` key

```
migration:
  dir: resources/migrations/v0.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explaining where your issue is - the `dynamodb-handler.yml` file is missing the key, `Resources`. In the [serverless-dynamodb-local docs](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dynamodb-local), you can see the redundant `resources` & `Resources` keys. So your `dynamodb-handler.yml` should begin like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  userAccount:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
```

Note that all other external resources must begin with the same key, i.e. `api-gateway-handler.yml` in your example.

Additionally, if you're having difficulty creating the table when starting serverless offline, or you're using a persistent docker dynamodb instead, migrate with the following command:

```sh
npx serverless dynamodb migrate
```